# Deploying an Angular App in Node JS (express) server through http-server

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm trying to put an angular application in "production" on a local server that is generated by the http-server tool, but it does not return the   of the index.html.

I followed these steps ...

1. ng build --prod (this throws me the project folder for production like this -> "dist / project-erp")
   [image: Step 1]
2. http-server
   [image: Step 2]
3. web server
   [image: Step 3]

**Update:**
So, I changed the base route to "/" but still happening in same situation :/
[image: update 1]

[image: update 1.1]

Comment: the `<base href="/dist/project-erp/">` looks suspiciously like you have set the wrong base. after build there shouldn't be any ref to /dist because dist should be the webroot (including project-erp).. ideally when running http-server or any static server or deployment it should enter into ./dist/project-erp/ and then run like `./` meaning `<base href="/">` else your just opening up your src files to download

Comment: @LawrenceCherone So, I changed the base route to "/" but still happening in same situation :/

Answer (score 0):

After many tests of building the project, the solution to launch it on the Express server (it worked for now) is to just do the command "ng build" instead of "ng build --prod", then the folders "dist / project-erp "put them on the backend server.

Comment: or you could have done `http-server ./dist/project-erp`